# What is the name of the documents that describes changes and implementation?

Tags: documentation

In our development process, we have documents for each task/feature that describe

- API changes
- API logic
- Data flow (if needed)
- Database changes
- How client should interact with new/modified APIs
- Other information to clarify implementation

The target audience of the documents are developers who implement the feature, so they can implement the feature according to the document.

I am not sure how to call this document. For now we call it "technical specification" but I feel it is a bit more than that.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A document that describes the something to be implemented based on some requirements is indeed a specification.

But it’s technical specifications sounds as if it would describe the internals only. Since it also describes how the logic and usage will change for the clients, independently of the way the change will be imlemented, it could be considered as a functional specification (the API provides a technical “function”)